# Normalization settings table (with duplicates in the same cell and with different types in the same column)

Tags: sql, database-design, database-normalization

I have settings table like this:

```
 id | user_id | key              | value
 1  |    1    | show brand logos | true 
 2  |    1    | brand ids        | 1,3,4
 3  |    1    | search type      | advanced
```

I use this and it works somehow, but I have read about normalization and it brakes even first normalization form rules: single valued attributes (there is a cell with `1,3,4`) and attribute domain should not change (there are Boolean, String and Integers).

Have you any ideas how to normalize this table? I have searched a lot, but without success.

Comment: Give us an example result that you want.

Comment: I want to split this table without duplicates and without different types in the same column.

Comment: If all the values in the `value` column are atomic from the DB  point of view, i.e. no query needs to decompose the value into subvalues and all processing of the subvalues is at client side,  then `value` is fine.

Comment: So you just give a result example you want according to the settings table's data above, so we can understand your requirement better.

Comment: My goal is remain this data and achieve first normal form.

Comment: How many different kinds of keys are present? Only those three? or much more? Do they change in time?

Comment: There are Booleans, Strings and ids from different tables.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking for different values, like " show brand logos", etc.

Comment: Now I have about 15 different keys.

Answer (score 0):

create a key table:

```
id  | key
1   | show brand logos 
2   | brand ids
3   | search type
```

add three rows instead on one

```
id  | user_id | key             | value_bool| value_str| value_num
 1  |    1    | 1               | true      | null     | null
 2  |    1    | 2               | null      | null     | 1
 2  |    1    | 2               | null      | null     | 3
 2  |    1    | 2               | null      | null     | 4
 3  |    1    | 3               | null      | advanced | null
```

Comment: As I think this is partial solution. There are different types in the value column and it is impossible to add foreign constraint.

Comment: It is difficult to say exactly what your database model should look like. You also have to look at other tables. With the help of your example table it is not  possible to recommend a correct approach.
if you want to add another reference then you can save it in another column. I suppose you should reconsider your approach

Comment: OK, I vote you answer, but wait better solution also. :)